# FXC /Od problems on DirectX 10 Hardware

Tags: directx, shader, direct3d11

I'm having a weird problem with FXC and DirectX 11.  Running on a DirectX 10.0 compliant (admittedly crappy) integrated graphic card, my shaders are not working if I use FXC to compile them at build time with the flag **/Od**.  Looking at the graphics debugger in VS 2012, I see the input assembler and vertex shader stages of the graphics pipeline correctly, but the pixel shader stage is missing, so the geometry is never drawn to the framebuffer, like so: [image]

Using /O0 works, but then I lose the ability to debug shaders effectively (optimizations, even at /O0, seem to scramble the instructions, so they don't match the .fx source file)

On another machine, with a DirectX 11 card (GTX 560), /Od works fine.

Comment: Have you tried updating your graphics driver?  If the same shader bytecode works on a GTX 560 (and you're sure both are running at feature level 10+), it's unlikely that the problem is related to FXC.  If you want to be sure, you can try running the program using the WARP adapter (`D3D11CreateDevice(NULL,D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP,...`).

Comment: Show us vertex shader code. there may be anything, but I suspect problem with depth/stencil. Check if your geometry passes depth and stencil tests in "Pixel History" of graphics debugger. Run VS under shade debugger to check position values that will be passed to PS. Also, when you switch to debug shader, anything else changing? (maybe you switching whole project, so your CPU code also changes)